# Find data-id for each list item and add together

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list with nested ul elements in each, i want to be able to find the data-id attribute for each `.cart-select` item, add these together and then print this out somewhere. So for example, the first .cart-select item will have a value of 7.

So far i've added a function which goes through each .cart-select and finds data-id for  .bay-qty, however i'm not sure how to get  these values from each and add them together.

Can anyone help please?

```js
$('.cart-select').each(function() {
  var products = $('.list .cart-items', this) find('.bay-qty').data("id").count();
  $('<p>' + products + '</p>').appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<li class="cart-select">
  <li></li>
  <ul class="cart-items">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="bay-qty" data-id="1">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bay-qty" data-id="2">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bay-qty" data-id="4">3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>

  <li>
    <li class="cart-select">
      <li></li>
      <ul class="cart-items">
           <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="bay-qty" data-id="1">1</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </li>
      <li>
```

Comment: I don't understand your HTML. You have `<li>` tags nested inside other `<li>` tags (to make a nested list you need `<li><ul></ul><li>`), and then `<ul>` tags which have `<table>` tags inside; the only element semantically valid inside a `<ul>` is an `<li>`. Also, your `<td>` tags have no values, so all that is rendered is some bullets.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes you're right. This is a simplified version of the code i'm working on just to give you an example and by mistake i've typed the .cart-items as a <li> rather than a <ul>. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to convert each element to its value, then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to sum the array:

```
var sum = $('.list .cart-items', this)
  .find('.bay-qty')
  .map(function () { return this.data("id"); })
  .get() // get the array
  .reduce(function (sum, value) { return sum + value; }, 0)
```